# How to update data to pie chart using vue-apexcharts

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, pie-chart

I want to create pie-chart with vue-apexcharts. I had data from API but I don't know how to update the chart's data.

```
 mounted() {
    axios
      .get("/data/episodes.json")
      .then(response => {
         console.log(response);
     });
  }
```

The chart I want to create is like this

[image]

Comment: You need to understand how the library (you get the pie-chart from) accepts the data. I have experience using `echart` and `chart.js`. Tell me the library you are using and we will figure it out together.

Comment: Hello, I am using vue-apexcharts.

Comment: I don't have experience on using vue-apexcharts but I have read their documentation and I wrote my understanding. Here is their doc link https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/pie-charts/simple-pie-chart/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding on doing, ...

first you have to define the data and option values of chart.

```
components: {
    apexchart: VueApexCharts,
  },
  data: {
    series: [],
    chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        width: 380,
        type: "pie",
      },
      labels: [],
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            chart: {
              width: 200,
            },
            legend: {
              position: "bottom",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
```

Now on mount you have call your api to get the data and update the chart information. like this ...
I'm thinking of you server would return an array of objects having value and key.

```
 mounted() {
    axios.get("/data/episodes.json").then((response) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        this.data.series.push(response.data[i].value);
        this.data.chartOptions.labels.push(response.data[i].key);
      }
    });
  },
```

Finally, you have to add the chart component to the vue template. like this.

```
<div id="chart">
    <apexchart type="pie" width="380" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexchart>
</div>
```

Done,

Ask me if it is not clear for you.